# How do I correctly manage the disposing of a DataContext?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, dispose, idisposable

I have a web service that is quite heavy on database access. It works fine in test, but as soon as I put it in production and ramp up the load it starts churning out errors that are raised when something calls a method in the DataContext. The error is normally one of these:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.

but not always.

Any single web service requests can result as many as 10 or 15 database queries, and 1 or 2 updates.

I've designed my application with a data access layer which is a bunch of objects that represent the tables in my database which hold all the business logic. The is a separate project to my web service as it's shared with a Web GUI.

The data access objects derive from a base class which has a `GetDataContext()` method to initiate an instance of the data context whenever it's needed.

All throughout my data access objects I've written this:

```
using (db = GetDataContext())
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

which happily creates/uses/disposes my DataContext (created by sqlmetal.exe) object for each and every database interaction.

After many hours of head scratching, I think I've decided that the cause of my errors is that under load the datacontext object is being created and disposed way too much, and I need to change things to share the same datacontext for the duration of the web service request.

I found [this article](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx) on the internet which has a DataContextFactory that seems to do exactly what I need.

However, now that I've implemented this, and the DataContext is saved as an item in the HttpContext, I get...

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'

...whenever my datacontext is used more than once. This is because my `using (...) {}` code is disposing my datacontext after its first use.

So, my question is... before I go through my entire data access layer and remove loads of `usings`, what is the correct way to do this? I don't want to cause a memory leak by taking out the `usings`, but at the same time I want to share my datacontext across different data access objects.

Should I just remove the `usings`, and manually call the dispose method just before I return from the web service request? If so then how go I make sure I capture everything bearing in mind I have several `try-catch` blocks that could get messy.

Is there another better way to do this? Should I just forget about disposing and hope everything is implicitly cleaned up?

**UPDATE**

The problem doesn't appear to be a performance issue... requests are handled very quickly, no more than about 200ms. In fact I have load tested it by generating lots of fake requests with no problems.

As far as I can see, it is load related for one of two reasons:

- A high number of requests causes concurrent requests to affect each other
- The problem happens more frequently simply because there are a lot of requests.

When the problem does occur, the application pool goes into a bad state, and requires a recycle to get it working again.

Comment: @abatishchev: Thanks for the retag... but why did you revert all my typo fixes?

Comment: 17 `DataContext` instances per request doesn't seem much to me. The creation of a `DataContext` is very light. It might win you some performance, because it caches entities, but that's all. Did you profile the queries send to the database? How many queries are fired during 1 request?

Comment: @Steven: All of the queries are done via stored procs which may contain a few queries. It does around 24 sql queries in total per request. The performance is not the problem though, the request completes in around 200ms (measured by log file timestamps). The problem is when more than 20 requests hit in quick succession, that's when it starts to error.

Comment: What makes you think that the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object has anything to do with the disposing of the datacontext? I would rather think about a problem with deferred loading of related entities or something like that?

Comment: @BG100: @Plean might be spot on, and again, 24 sql queries and 24 `DataContext` creations is peanuts. I advice you to do some more performance measuring to find the actual bottleneck in the system. I'm pretty sure the number of `DataContext` is not the problem. Run the creations in a tight loop to see how many you can do in a second.

Comment: @Plean: Can you explain a bit more about "deferred loading of related entities"? I'm not sure what this means...

Comment: @Steven: This doesn't seem to be a performance problem in the sense things take too long.... the problem occurs when there are lots of requests per min, either due to high load or it could be because there are more requests so the problem occurs more frequently. When it does occur, the app pool seems to go into a bad state and I need to recycle to get it working again.

Comment: @BG100: I can't imagine this being caused by L2S. Could it be a race condition? Are you storing the `DataContext` somewhere?

Comment: @Steven: It could be a race condition, but I have no idea how to debug this! No, I'm diligently creating a new DataContext for each and every database interaction surrounding it in a using block... hence my thoughts about changing it to share the DataContext between queries... but as yet I haven't done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself...

I had a base class that had a method that would create the DataContext instance, like this:

```
public abstract class MyBase {

    protected static DataContext db = null;

    protected static DataContext GetDataContext() {
        return new DataContext("My Connection String");
    }

    // rest of class
}
```

And then, in the classes that inherited MyBase where I wanted to do my queries, I had statements like this:

```
using (db = GetDataContext()) { ... }
```

The thing is, I wanted to access the database from both static methods and non-static methods, and so in my base class, I'd declared the `db` variable as static... Big mistake!

If the DataContext variable is declared as static, during heavy loads when lots of things are happening at the same time the DataContext is shared among the requests, and if something happens on the DataContext at exactly the same time it screws up the instance of the DataContext, and the Database connection stored in the Application pool for all subsequent requested until it's recycled, and the database connection is refreshed.

So, the simple fix is to change this:

```
protected static DataContext db = null;
```

to this:

```
protected DataContext db = null;
```

...which will break all of the `using` statements in the static methods. But this can easily be fixed by declaring the DataContext variable in the `using` instead, like this:

```
using (DataContext db = GetDataContext()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I would prefer the unit-of-work approach using `using`, sometimes it doesn't always fit into your design. Ideally you'd want to ensure that you are freeing up your `SqlConnection` when you're done with it so that anothe request has a chance of grabbing that connection from the pool. If that is not possible, what you would need is some assurance that the context is disposed of after each request. This could be done a couple of ways:

1. If you're using WebForms, you can tie the disposal of the `DataContext` at the end of the page lifecycle. Make a check to the `HttpContext.Items` collection to determine if the last page had a data context, and if so, dispose of it.
2. Create a dedicated `IHttpModule` which attaches an event to the end of the request, where you do the same as above.

The problem with both of the above solutions, is that if you are under heavy load, you'll find that a lot of requests hang about waiting for a connection to be made available, likely timing out. You'll have to weigh up the risks.

All in all, the unit-of-work approach would still be favoured, as you are releasing the resource as soon as it is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have, for example, an object that references another object (i.e. a join between two tables) and you try to access the referenced object after the context has been disposed of. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Father> fathers;
using (var db = GetDataContext())
{
  // Assume a Father as a field called Sons of type IEnumerable<Son>
  fathers = db.Fathers.ToList();
}

foreach (var father in fathers)
{
  // This will get the exception you got
  Console.WriteLine(father.Sons.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

This can be avoided by forcing it to load all the referenced objects like this:

```
IEnumerable<Father> fathers;
using (var db = GetDataContext())
{
  var options = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
  options.LoadWith<Father>(f => f.Sons);
  db.LoadOptions = options;
  fathers = db.Fathers.ToList();
}

foreach (var father in fathers)
{
  // This will no longer throw
  Console.WriteLine(father.Sons.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Comment: This was my initial thoughts on what the problem was, however I have checked and there is no reference to an object returned from the datacontext outside of the using block. This is a non-deterministic problem that I cannot replicate in a development environment. If your suggestion was the problem then I'd easily be able to replicate this.

Comment: @BG100: Indeed. Best of luck then. Heisenbugs are always a pain.