# Disposing Database context with using statement in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, using

I'm using entity framework in my MVC website and I'm disposing my database context using using-statement. Now my question is if I close using statement after return, would the database context disposed properly or not. Ex:

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(){

      using (var DB = new DatabaseContext()){

       ....           

       return View();                
      }
 }
```

Do I have to close the using statement before return? Or it would be disposed properly in the way I'm using it.

Comment: This should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381747/how-do-i-correctly-manage-the-disposing-of-a-datacontext

Comment: What you have is good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356307/will-a-idisposable-be-disposed-if-the-using-block-returns and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254815/dispose-and-return-values-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to close the using statement before return? Or it would be disposed properly in the way I'm using it?

It will be automagically disposed for you. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356307/will-a-idisposable-be-disposed-if-the-using-block-returns) for more information .The `Dispose` method is called however the `using` statement is executed, unless it was an abrupt whole-process termination. The most common cases are:

- A `return` within the block
- An exception being thrown (and not caught) within the block
- Reaching the end of the block naturally

Basically a `using` statement is mostly syntactic sugar for a `try`/`finally` block - and `finally` has all the same properties.

From section 8.13 of the [C# 4 specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356307/will-a-idisposable-be-disposed-if-the-using-block-returns):

> A `using` statement is stranslated into three parts: acquisition, usage, and disposal. Usage of the resource is implicitly enclosed in a `try` statement that includes a `finally` clause. This `finally` clause disposes of the resource.

Comment: Based on your common cases if we have return within using statement it won't be disposed?